# Is there a way to put AutoScalingGroup instances to stand by via cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm thinking of using cloud formation as a means of blue-green deployment.

Part of it is putting instances of the Autoscaling group instances on stand by.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling groups are responsible for launching and terminating Amazon EC2 instances. Note that instances are **launched** as new instances -- they are not kept on standby.

You can certainly do blue-green deployments by using two separate CloudFormation stacks, each with their own Auto Scaling group and, presumably, Elastic Load Balancer.

Both Auto Scaling groups would be 'operating', but not necessarily receiving traffic. You would then need some mechanism to 'switch' between the blue/green groups, such as changing a DNS entry in Route 53 to point to the different Load Balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to John's Answer, On route 53 you can use weighted load balancing to route traffic. It allows you to route percentage traffic to the setups.